# Table size, alignment and columns alignment

Tags: tables, miktex, texmaker, width, alignment

I'm new with LaTeX.
I want to have two tables. The first table renders fine.
For the second table, I want it to take full page width and I want text from first column to be aligned left and text from second column to be aligned right.

I have tried the following based on some researches, but table 2 is not taking full with and while the alignment inside columns is as I expect, the table itself is aligned left.
(I'm not sure what `htbp` is, it comes from some example.)

```
\begin{center} \Large
    \begin{tabular}{ l r }  
        \emph{Text1} & Text2\\ 
        \emph{Text3} & Text4
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\vskip 7cm

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l r}
            \ Text5 & Text6\\
            \ Text7 & Text8\\
            \ Text9 & Text10\\
            \ Text11 & Text12\\
            \ Text13 & Text14
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

When I try the following, all previous elements on my page get extra spaces, like the whole page is stretched and second table ends on next page, which should not happen.

```
\begin{center} \Large
    \begin{tabular}{ l r }  
        \emph{Text1} & Text2\\ 
        \emph{Text3} & Text4
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\vskip 9cm

\begin{center} \Large
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l r }
        \ Text5 & Text6\\
        \ Text7 & Text8\\
        \ Text9 & Text10\\
        \ Text11 & Text12\\
        \ Text13 & Text14
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
```

Comment: A `rabularx` environment should have at least one `X` column.

Comment: What is one X column?

Comment: It is defined by the `tabularx` package : the `X` columns share the remaining space on the line, after the other columns have been placed.

Comment: What are the `\ ` in every row of the `tabularx` supposed to do?

Comment: Then maybe it's not tabularx I need to use? I actually want each column to take 50% width.

Comment: @leandriis : I'm not sure but if I don't have them, compilation give some "missing number" error.

Comment: Will there be text in any of the columns that is wider than 50% of the textwidth? e.g. Do you need linebreaks inside of table cells? Please clarify.

Comment: Replace in the table preamble `{lr}` with `\{X>{\raggedleft}X}`.

Comment: @leandriis: No, and no. Short texts, no linebreaks.

Comment: Regarding: "but if I don't have them, compilation give some "missing number" error": I can't reproduce that. ou definitely should not need them there.

Comment: What about using `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l r @{}}
         Text5 & Text6\\
         Text7 & Text8\\
         Text9 & Text10\\
         Text11 & Text12\\
         Text13 & Text14
    \end{tabular*}`? Most likely this will give you the desired result.

Comment: @Bernard: I just tried, I get "! Argument of \TX@get@body has an extra }.<inserted text>\par ...n{tabularx}{\textwidth}\{X>{\raggedleft}X}"

Comment: Youi should post a complete (minimal) code reproducing the problem.

Comment: @leandriis: This one seems to work thank you. Not sure what "tabular*" is, is it yet another package?

Comment: @leandriis As soon as I add my text I need to add the "\" at the start of each line. From what I just tested, it is because one of my texts currently has a part that is between "[...]" (It's actually a place holder for some info that I don't have yet.

Comment: @leandriis: If you post your comment as Answer, I could check it as solution.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an MWE (Minimal Working Example), which cover most of the comments in your question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum} % generate dummy text filler

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
\Large
    \begin{tabular}{ l r }
        \emph{Text1} & Text2\\
        \emph{Text3} & Text4
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\lipsum[11]% for dummy text

\begin{center} \Large
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
         Text5  & Text6\\
         Text7  & Text8\\
         Text9  & Text10\\
         Text11 & Text12\\
         Text13 & Text14
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
However, people usual add to table at least top and bottom lines:
\begin{center}
\Large
    \begin{tabular}{ l r }
        \hline
        \emph{Text1} & Text2    \\ 
        \emph{Text3} & Text4    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center} \Large
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \hline
         Text5  & Text6     \\
         Text7  & Text8     \\
         Text9  & Text10    \\
         Text11 & Text12    \\
         Text13 & Text14    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which generate:

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

I strongly encourage you to read some introductory text about tables. For example [wiki: latex tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

For table design, you may choose environments, as `tabular`, which is part of LaTeX kernel, `tabularx`, `tabulary`, `longtable`, `xltabular` etc, which are provided by packages of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

> I actually want each column to take 50% width

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % nice rules
\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{.3\textwidth}{XL}
\toprule
Text5 & Text6\\
Text13 & Text14\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> I want it to take full page width

I refuse to make such aberration with only two narrow columns, but how change `.3\textwidth` is obvious, right?